# dependent => destroy on a "has_many through" association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

Apparently dependent => destroy is ignored when also using the :through option.

So I have this...

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comment_users, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :comment_users
  ...
end
```

...but deleting a Comment does not result in the associated comment_user records getting deleted.

What's the recommended approach, then, for cascade deletes when using :through?

Thanks

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Apparently :dependent is not ignored!

The real issue was that I was calling `Comment.delete(id)` which goes straight to the db, whereas I now use `Comment.destroy(id)` which loads the Comment object and calls destroy() on it. This picks up the `:dependent => :destroy` and all is well.

Comment: Indeed! I had a similar issue except I was getting foreign key errors even though I was using `dependent: :destroy`. Problem was I was using `obj.delete` instead of `obj.destroy` so the dependents weren't getting deleted, thus the integrity error.

Answer (score 12):

The original poster's solution is valid, however I wanted to point out that this only works if you have an id column for that table. I prefer my many-to-many tables to only be the two foreign keys, but I had to remove my "id: false" from the migration table definition for cascading delete to work. Having this functionality definitely outweighs not having an id column on the table.

Comment: Thank you! I just spent half a day trying to figure that out by myself.

Answer (score 8):

If you have a polymorphic association, you should do what @blogofsongs said but with a foreign_key attribute like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities , dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: :trackable_id
end
```