# Rails - Help understanding how to use :dependent => :destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activemodel

I have the following models:

```
User (id)
Project (id)
Permission (project_id, user_id)
Thread (project_id)
ThreadParticipation (thread_id, user_id)
```

So that's working nicely, problem is this. When a user leaves or is removed from a project, I need all their ThreadParticipation's for that project deleted.

Example, so if user(15), leaves project(3) by deleting the permission (user_id =>15, project_id => 3), I need rails to automatically then delete all related ThreadParticipation records (where ThreadParticipation through thread, belongs to project_id 3, and ThreadParticipation.user_id = 15.

I've tried this, but it's not doing anything:

```
has_many :thread_participations, :foreign_key => :user_id, :dependent => :destroy
```

Thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Permission` Model, do this:

```
before_destroy :delete_thread_participation

private
      def delete_thread_participation
         if self.threadparticipation 
           self.threadparticipation.delete_all "project_id ="+self.project_id+"and user_id="+self.user_id
         end
      end
```

This is considering you have relationships defined in the models

Comment: Thanks but I don't want this to happen when the user is deleted. I want the ThreadParticipations to be delete when the PERMISSION is deleted. The permission joins the user to the project.

Comment: Edited. You can also have a cascading effect, by calling a function within `delete_thread_participation` like `self.user_id.some_function` or `self.project_id.some_function`

Comment: Wouldn't this be better as `delete_all(:project_id => project_id, :user_id => user_id)`

Comment: @Ryan Bigg: Sure. Looks better.

Comment: @Ryan, how would that work, where would it go? Doesn't it need to stay which model to delete on?

Answer (score 2):

Are you maybe using `delete` instead of `destroy`? Using `destroy` will cause dependents to be removed while `delete` does not. [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399394/dependent-destroy-on-a-has-many-through-association)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Project
  has_many :threads
  has_many :thread_participations, :through => :threads      
end

class Permission
  belongs_to :project

  after_destroy :destroy_thread_participations

  def destroy_thread_participations
    ThreadParticipation.delete_all(
      :id => project.thread_participations.find_all_by_user_id(user_id)
    )
  end
end
```

Use `destroy_all` instead of `delete_all` if you have `*_destroy` callbacks in the `ThreadParticipation` model. The `delete_all` call is faster than `destroy_all` as it performs deletion of multiple rows in one DB call and does not have the overhead of invoking the `*_destroy` callbacks.

Comment: Just gave this a try, it error'd with: ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :thread in model Permission

Comment: I that's bec thread does not belong to permission. Thread belongs to Project. And a user has a permission record that links them between User/Project.

Comment: Updated my answer take a look.