# How can I make a polymorphic connection be dependent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations, polymorphism

I am trying to make my image_maps get destroyed when either a product or image is deleted. Here is the code.

```
class ImageMap < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :image
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :image_maps, :as => :imageable
  has_many :images, :through => :image_maps
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :image_maps, :as => :imageable, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Right now the image_maps do not get destroyed when you delete an image and i still need to figure out how to get it to work for products too.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your dependent should go to the ImageMap model.

If i remember correctly, this is what Rails checks on the associated models to see whether they need to be destroyed.

Comment: I tried it, but when i tried to associate an image with a product it deleted the product lol.

Comment: hmm, because of the associations, i suppose you need a callback. Maybe this helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998239/rails-help-understanding-how-to-use-dependent-destroy