# Rails, How to setup a Dependent Destroy for a nested model set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, dependent-destroy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rails - Help understanding how to use :dependent => :destroy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998239/rails-help-understanding-how-to-use-dependent-destroy)

I have the following models:

```
User
Permission (user_id, group_id)
Group
Conversation (group_id)
ConversationParticipation (conversation_id)
```

What I want to do in my Permissions model is, when a permission is destory, delete all the related ConversationParticipations based on the group_id and user_id.

I tried this:

```
class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :conversation_participations, :through => :group, :source => :conversations, :dependent => :destroy
```

But that doesn't seem to be cutting it just yet. Suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the Rails Documentation for `has_many`

> **:dependent**
>
> If set to :destroy all the
>   associated objects are destroyed
>   alongside this object by calling their
>   destroy method. If set to :delete_all
>   all associated objects are deleted
>   without calling their destroy method.
>   If set to :nullify all associated
>   objects’ foreign keys are set to NULL
>   without calling their save callbacks.
>   If set to :restrict this object cannot
>   be deleted if it has any associated
>   object.
>
> **Warning: This option is
>   ignored when used with :through
>   option.**

You could always try [callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).