# Has_many through association with dependant: destroy not destroying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

I have this model

```
class XmlImport < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :video
   belongs_to :user

   has_many :events, through: :event_import_records, dependent: :destroy
   has_many :event_import_records, dependent: :destroy

   has_attached_file :xml
   validates_attachment_content_type :xml, :content_type => ["text/xml"]
end
```

The `:event_import_records` entries are being destroyed. But the `:events` are not.

- Is the `dependent:destroy` on the `has_many through` association valid?
- Is there another way of writing it? If that is not correct
- How can I destroy all the `events` associated to the `XmlImport` through the `event_import_records`?

Comment: this is what i found, hope it's helpful [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399394/dependent-destroy-on-a-has-many-through-association)

Comment: I've read that one, but in that question the problem he had was the one I've already solved! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You can find at the [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) that: "If using with the :through option, the association on the join model must be a belongs_to, and the records which get deleted are the join records, rather than the associated records." I understand that it delete the joins records but not the associated by through.

If I were you, I try:

```
class EventImportRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events, dependent: :destroy
end
```

If not work I swap the order of the `has_many` relations on the `XmlImport` model, because of "Note that :dependent is implemented using Rails' callback system, which works by processing callbacks in order. Therefore, other callbacks declared either before or after the :dependent option can affect what it does." Also find at the same page of the Rails API.