# Rails 4: counter_cache in has_many :through association with dependent: :destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through, counter-cache

Although similar questions have already been asked:

- [counter_cache with has_many :through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256897/counter-cache-with-has-many-through)
- [dependent => destroy on a "has_many through" association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399394/dependent-destroy-on-a-has-many-through-association)
- [has_many :through with counter_cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991118/has-many-through-with-counter-cache)

none of them actually addresses my issue.

I have three models, with a has_many :through association :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :calendars, through: :administrations
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :administrations
  has_many :users, through: :administrations
end

class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calendar
end
```

The join Administration model has the following attributes:

```
id
user_id
calendar_id
role
```

I would like to count how many `calendars` each `user` has and how many `users` each `calendar` has.

I was going to go with counter_cache as follows:

```
class Administration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, counter_cache: :count_of_calendars
  belongs_to :calendar, counter_cache: :count_of_users
end
```

(and, of course, the corresponding migrations to add `:count_of_calendars` to the `users` table and `:count_of_users` to the `calendars` table.)

But then, I stumbled upon [this warning in Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter-cache):

> 4.1.2.4 :dependent
>
> If you set the :dependent option to:
>
> - :destroy, when the object is destroyed, destroy will be called on its associated objects.
> - :delete, when the object is destroyed, all its associated objects will be deleted directly from the database without calling their
>     destroy method.
>
> **You should not specify this option on a belongs_to association that is
>   connected with a has_many association on the other class. Doing so can
>   lead to orphaned records in your database.**

Therefore, what would be a good practice to count how many `calendars` each `user` has and how many `users` each `calendar` has?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `dependent: :destroy` will destroy the associated records, but it won't update the `counter_cache`, so you may have wrong count in `counter_cache`. Instead you can implement a callback that will destroy the associated records, and update your `counter_cache`.

```
class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :administrations
  has_many :users, through: :administrations


  before_destroy :delete_dependents

  private
  def delete_dependents
    user_ids = self.user_ids
    User.delete_all(:calendar_id => self.id)
    user_ids.each do |u_id|
      Calendar.reset_counters u_id, :users
    end
  end
end
```

And similarly, implement this for `User` model too

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like an interesting solution. One question though: what does `:question_id`refer to?

Comment: Thanks, that's clearer. So, you recommend that I completely remove `dependant: :destroy`?

Comment: yes, as `dependant: :destroy` does the same function, it destroys the associated records upon destruction. while, here u r doing it manually, but preserving the counter_cache

Comment: Replace `User.delete_all(:calendar_id => self.id)` with `Administration.delete_all(calendar_id: self.id)`.

Comment: You guys are talking dependent... not dependant.