# Counter cache on polymorphic many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I would like to have counter cache on many-to-many association.
Everything works fine, even taggings_count is increment every time, but I have a problem when associated model is removed. The column taggings_count isn't updated.

Article model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings, as: :taggable
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings, dependent: :destroy
end
```

join table:

```
class Tagging < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag, counter_cache: true
  belongs_to :taggable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Tag model:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :articles, through: :taggings, dependent: :destroy
end
```

When I remove (by destroy method) an article from database, row from join table is removed as well, but no decrement on taggings_count. Here is the output:

```
  Article Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `articles`.* FROM `articles` WHERE `articles`.`slug` = 'test'  ORDER BY `articles`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  Tag Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `tags`.* FROM `tags` INNER JOIN `taggings` ON `tags`.`id` = `taggings`.`tag_id` WHERE `taggings`.`taggable_id` = 29 AND `taggings`.`taggable_type` = 'Article'  ORDER BY `tags`.`taggings_count` DESC
  Tagging Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `taggings`.* FROM `taggings` WHERE `taggings`.`taggable_id` = 29 AND `taggings`.`taggable_type` = 'Article' AND `taggings`.`tag_id` = 26
  SQL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM `taggings` WHERE `taggings`.`taggable_id` = 29 AND `taggings`.`taggable_type` = 'Article' AND `taggings`.`tag_id` = 26
  SQL (0.2ms)  DELETE FROM `articles` WHERE `articles`.`id` = 29
   (3.5ms)  COMMIT
```

Comment: This related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275640/rails-4-counter-cache-in-has-many-through-association-with-dependent-destroy

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. I had join table (taggings) without ids. I had to remove `id: false` from the migration.